# Can the surface of a neutron star move faster than light? How length contraction manifests there?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, faster-than-light, neutron-stars

It is known that any Kerr black hole is surrounded by ergosphere, inside which everything rotates around the black hole faster than light. Since ergosphere is greater than event horizon, one can speculate that neutron stars also can have ergospheres.

If so, their equator should contract to a point due to high speed. Does this happen? If no, why?

Comment: The fastest *known* neutron star spin speed is 0.24c. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_J1748%E2%88%922446ad

Answer (score 2):

In general, neutron stars are not compact enough to have an ergosphere.

On average, the radius of a neutron star is much greater than its corresponding Schwarzschild radius.

Some astrophysicists have argued that a neutron star can *develop* an ergosphere, though in such cases, the ergosphere may develop *inside* the stellar fluid (if the star is sufficiently compact).